# Time-varying parameter estimates

Tags: regression, identifiability

I have some basic conceptual misunderstanding of how to back out parameter estimates from the following function:

$W_{it+1} = \alpha_1 \frac{R_{t+1}}{R_t} W_{it} + \alpha_2 \frac{R_{t+1}}{R_t^2} W_{it}^2 + \alpha_3 \frac{R_{t+1}}{R_t} N_{it} W_{it} + \alpha_4 R_{t+1} N_{it} + \alpha_5 R_{t+1} N_{it}^2$

The observables include $W_{it}$ and $N_{it}$, and the paper uses this function to jointly estimate the parameters $\alpha_j, \ j=1,...,5$ and the time-varying parameters $R_t$, $t=1,...,T+1$. They normalize $R_1 = 1$ and back out the remaining $R_t$. My first thought is that I need to interact a time dummy with each of my observables to get time-varying coefficient estimates. However, this quickly becomes over-identified and I have no single solution for $R_t$. How could something like this work?

Suppose I have two years of data, so that I want to estimate $R_2$ and $R_3$ after setting $R_1 = 1$. I have the following estimates $A_j^t$, $j=1,...,5$ and $t=1,2$ from my regression equation:
$$A_1^1 = \alpha_1 R_{2}, \ \ A_2^1 = \alpha_2 R_{2}, \ \ A_3^1 = \alpha_3 R_{2}, \ \ A_4^1 = \alpha_4 R_2, \ \ A_5 = \alpha_5 R_2$$
With just these, I have 5 equations and 6 unknowns. Now estimates from the next year:
$$A_1^2 = \alpha_1 R_{3}/R_2, \ \ A_2^2 = \alpha_2 R_{3}/R_2^2, \ \ A_3^2= \alpha_3 R_{3}/R_2, \ \ A_4^1 = \alpha_4 R_3, \ \ A_5 = \alpha_5 R_3$$
From the next year's worth of data I have
Now I have 10 equations 7 unknowns ($\alpha_j, \ j=1,...,5$ and $R_2$ and $R_3$). Not great. Whatever it is I should be doing here is not obvious to me. Given that the paper (Shaw 1989) doesn't detail what they're doing here perhaps it should. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you provide a proper reference. I would assume you have a misunderstanding and R are not parameters. But unless you provide the details of the paper no one can help you.

Comment: Sure, here's the reference: https://www.jstor.org/stable/2526656. They do estimate R_t. Now I think I may need to do some kind of log transformation of the function, but I'm still not sure.